# Graph between current and voltage in an inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

I want to know can we draw a graph between current and voltage of an inductor putting current on the $y$ axis and voltage on the $x$ axis. Also keeping $t$ and $L$ constant. If so, please can someone help solve this query?
I have used Faraday's equation both derivative and integral form, for an inductor. But If I put values like $t=10$ s and $L=5$ mh, and then try it out for different values of voltage, the graph is drawn linear. This is my work, can someone please explain how an inductor behaves as an ohmic resistor, as it isn't an ohmic resistor. That's why I think my answers are wrong. So if someone can elaborate on my questions it would be good.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage on an inductor, $V_L = -L\frac{\mathrm d I}{\mathrm d t}$.  I don't see a meaningful graph with a fixed ($t$).  Calculate ($I$) and ($V_L$) as functions of time and then plot them against each other. The result will depend on your chosen circuit.